# first_or_create causing issues when creating object with non-valid parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Good morning,

Trying to find the best way to avoid the current situation I am in so..
I have a class A 
which has the following attributes a,b,c,d

When create is called on A, I first check to see if an instance of A exists with the following parameters a,b,c.

Now the line I am using to check the database and create if necessary is

```
@foo = A.where(:a => params[:A][:a], :b => params[:A][:b],:c => params[:A][:c]).first_or_create!
```

Class A has the following validations for a,b,c

```
a's length > 3 & < 15
b must be true (checkbox must be checked)
c's length >50 & < 500
```

When a user is passing in a blank form I will receive errors generated from the above line.
I understand that it is caused by the controller attempting to create an object A that does not meet the validations.

Is the best way to go about this using `begin rescue end` or error checking pre-first_or_create! ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your two options is better `begin rescue end` so you don't repeat code you already have in model.

Another option is to use `first_or_create` without exclamation mark, so your code does not raise error, and then you could show errors in view. I would say this is equivalent to `begin rescue end` because you could show show errors in your view in rescue part.

Comment: I will give the non-! a go and see if it doesn't break anything. Thanks for the heads up.